# Another approach on the four color theroem

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, coloring

I've tried to understand why every map can be colored with 4 colors and I think I found a reason for that, but I don't know if my statements and conclusions are correct. Could you check it?

[First part](https://hobbymathematician.com/fcmthrm/) shows why 5 countries cannot be adjacent to each other

In the [second part](https://hobbymathematician.com/fcthrm2/) I tried to prove the theorem using the statement from the first part.

It is not written in a scientific language.

Comment: Be extremely cautious with claiming your own proof of 4CT (especially written without rigor!). This theorem is famous for convincing many professional mathematicians that they had proofs when they did not. For instance, a false proof due to Kempe was believed to be true by the mathematical community for about a decade in the 19th century.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was thinking what title to use in the blogpost. Eventually I ended up with prove of the 4CT. I wanted to make it clear that the goal of the article was to prove the theorem, even though I was certain that mistakes will be found in it. But I see why this title is confusing, so I will change it.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer** : I have not read fully your presentation, only the first page so far (and quickly), so this is a first comment on your work. Don't hesitate to correct me if I misread.

In this page you state :

> In order to disprove this theory, 5 countries need to be adjacent to each other at the same time. This way 4 colors will not be sufficient

This is true, but not sufficient. The graph colouring number is a global property of the graph, here you are only looking at the local case. Using graph theory methodology you are using the fact that the chromatic number of a graph is at least its clique number (the largest number of mutually adjacent vertices) :
$$ \chi(G)\geq \omega(G)$$

However, the colouring number being a global property, you will have some graphs, where there are no 5 vertices all adjacent (which is equivalent in your case of not having 5 countries adjacent), but still requiring 5 colours. For example

[image]

This graph is not 4-colorable, you need 5 colours, but its clique number is only 4. It is non-planar obviously, but the fact that it is not 4-colorable does not come from including a clique of size 5. You need other properties of planar graph to prove that they are 4-colorable.

**Edit on integer series :**
In your second page you talk about *integer series*, representing the number of adjacent countries for each country. This is known as degree sequence in graph theory. A degree sequence that represents (at least) one graph is called feasible. Be careful this does not means that it represents a maps, for this it would need to represent a planar graph.

As you already found, there are some easy restriction on feasible degree sequence. The feasibility of a degree sequence is solved by the [Erdos-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem#:%7E:text=The%20Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai%20theorem%20is,sequence%20of%20a%20simple%20graph.) :

> A sequence of non-negative integers $d_{1}\geq \cdots \geq d_{n}$ can be represented as the degree sequence of a finite simple graph on $n$ vertices if and only if $d_{1}+\cdots +d_{n}$ is even and
> $$\sum^{k}_{i=1}d_i\leq k(k-1)+ \sum^n_{i=k+1} \min (d_i,k)$$
> holds for every k in $1\leq k\leq n$.

You should also have a look at the [Havel–Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm). I do not know if there are similar partial results for feasible planar degree sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, many new things for me. You mentioned there are other properties for a planar graph to prove that they are 4-colorable. What if we would like to prove that a map that requires 5 colors to color cannot be planar (possible to draw)? My understanding was that even some unfeasible (I hope I use this right) integer series can be 4-colored as a graph, but series that needs 5 colors are always unfeasible, resulting in a non-planar graph, that cannot be drawn as a map.